# Clean OsS on MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine

I am getting really desperate with my beloved MacBook Pro (8.1 early 2011). As some may know, these models can't update to Mojave natively. There is a patch by Dosdude though to make things work. By now I got some general questions on how this crap actually boots up, so here is my desperate journey:

Since my DVD drive stopped working I replaced it with an SSD a couple of years ago. This resulted in not being able to get Bootcamp to work anymore (it needs the internal drive with some cd) all attempts to install via bootable USB or external drive failed. I ended up installing windows 7 in some VM then copying it to a partition on the SSD. It involved an entire week of finding out about bootloaders and such to get it running. Finally I had a dual boot mac again.

Then I updated to Mojave using the patch. Things worked fine until there was an update which I unfortunately installed. The Mac would not boot into the OS but into Windows. The OS partition was not even found anymore. DisK Utility said the ssd can't be read due to unknown filesystem. All the information was replaced with "FFFFFFFF..."

Being tired of this random stuff I decided to wipe the SSD, including the Bootcamp partition and set up a new OS. On the same day things got weird already. The SSD said there are 200 GB of deletable disk space. Googling told me that this happens due to automatic time machine backups (my disk only contained 20GB of actual data) and that this space would disappear when backing up. So I tried this, wiped my old internal HDD and let Time Machine do its work there. It said it would save 200 GB of data. Whatever I thought. Back in the morning it was finished, but my internal HDD was only occupied by 13 GB data. My SSD still had 200 GB of deletable data. Even my old passwords that I used before the install in Safari were still there. I got mad, decided to wipe everything off all disks. I did so and installed clean Mojave on the SSD.

Finally I only had 13 GB of data on my disk. I started Time Machine and backed this state up on my HDD. Then I thought let's try this, rebooted with my patched USB, entered Disk Utility, deleted the entire SSD again, then tried to recover from my HDD via Time Machine. The progress bar would hit, 50% then my Mac reboots without message, ending up in the boot menu showing only my old HDD and the USB stick. The SSD is gone again. I am seriously annoyed by now, since the only option left is again to reinstall OS and Time Machine is pretty useless. Now I want to understand what the hell is happening?! Why is my SSD getting lost on some reboots? How do I get a clean install (any OS, I don't care which by now) which is anywhere close to being stable and backup-able?

Don't tell me about recovery or safety modes, both are not installed in my disk, online recovery is also useless. It would not accept my new appleId, but only the original one to which I lost my email account. Also it often fails when connecting to the internet, apparently the password of my wifi is too long to be checked by online recovery mode to get connected in the first place.

Or if you can explain, what the hell is a MacBook doing upon boot, what EFI loader or similar is it looking for? How can I see those files? Why does it keep some data when erasing the drive? Is it even traceable what my Mac does Upon boot/restore/install? What is the format to go for (Mojave needs apfs, but I can use an older OS too)? What is the best format for my HDD backup drive so that data can be backed up fast (20GB needs like 1 hour)?

Comment: You've got far too many questions here & more of a blog post than an actual, comprehensible question. If you want to start over from Internet recovery, wire up, don't use wifi. Format a single partition as HFS+, not APFS. Don't expect to be able to swap back from Windows using the control panel if you force it on there, because Windows can't read APFS. +10 other things you mentioned, all of which have rational explanations, mostly starting with "you used an unsupported hack"...

Comment: Okay so I tried the internet recovery. It wants to download Lion. After entering my currently used appleid it will tell me this product is not available, try again later. now i used some timemachine backup with el capitain on it. Tried a clean install using the given suggetions . Again I enter my id and again it will tell me this product is currently not available. Just give me any working solution on how to install osxx on the ssd, and how to back it up on my timemachine , so that it will br recoverable from this point ( also when old Backups got deleted)

Comment: Try changing your system date to a short time after the release date of the OS you're trying to get [within a year should do it]. You shouldn't need to sign in to get the OS your machine shipped with, but it's not something I've had to do in a long long time. I keep all the installers here as backups.

Comment: I am not able to change the system time. There are just the standard utilities like restore from time machine, get online help, disc utilty (online recovery mode). Any idea? Also how can I recreate a recovery partition? Downloading these tools is also tricky every time

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/04/set-system-time-mac-os-x-command-line/ Recovery is created by the installer.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks! I will save your aproach for the next time. I solved it by reinstalling mojave with my installer stick, on mojave I downloaded HighSierra (hidden in Store but can be found via direct link from apple) then it told me its outdated but also saves the Installer file under programs. I then created an highsierra installer stick via terminal. Rebooted from stick, deleted all drives. Formated as journaled (guid partition table) then completed the highsierra installation. Setted up TM to use the internal hdd. After backup I rebooted, formatted the sdd & restored highsierra from TM.

Comment: But there is a new problem. When I download safety updates on highsierra (softeare update app store) the currently last update tries to install mojave i guess.Maybe its due to something I changed to be able to install mojave when I tried the mojave patch or when I installed the BootCamp partition. I followed some Tutorial where you had to change the macs settings for certain stuff that was prohibited (like installing mojave) https://www.google.de/amp/s/eclecticlight.co/2019/07/29/apple-has-released-high-sierra-and-sierra-security-updates-2019-004-again/amp/

Comment: Ok now on second try it got installed.

Comment: Thanks @karel for fixing all my grammar and spelling mistakes <3